# XAML reuse specific UI elements

Tags: xaml, code-reuse

With Xamarin, I have a small UI element which acts as a content divider:

```
<BoxView StyleClass="contentDivider"
   HeightRequest="2"
   WidthRequest="1000"
   Margin="3, 0"/>
```

Since I use this a number of times I wanted to be able to have the code written down once, and reuse that code - just like a class with its instance (DRY). It's most likely me being a blind bat and not being able to find how it's done. So, how can I reuse XAML elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with **ContentViews** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts#contentview), which probably works better for larger reuse cases (using more XAML in the ContentView).

Yet, for such a small single element example as yours, you could really just consider using a global style (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application) which its looks like you already have with StyleClass="contentDivider", as long as you only want to override properties on a single element (like your BoxView).

Just add HeightRequest, WidthRequest and Margin to your style and your done.

```
<Style x:Key="contentDivider" TargetType="BoxView">
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,99,0,0" />
    ... etc
</Style>
```

Comment: This worked indeed. The StyleClass didn't work since I couldn't get the Width property to work properly. Thanks for the help, marked it as answer.